# Remove siblings with no children in tree in R

Tags: r

I am observing changes to a d3js tree that the user can grow or collapse. An update to the tree is returned by the shiny ui to the server (r) as a flattened json and mapped into a dataframe.

I want to locate siblings that do not have at all children, or only the sibling that have children and prune them

Here is an example of such a dataframe

`x=data.frame(cyl=c(4,4,4,6,6,8),vs=c(0,1,1,0,1,NA),am=c(NA,0,1,rep(NA,3)))`

In this example I want to prune from this tree below at ggplot/8 and ggplot/4/0

[image: tree]

Comment: Where do you want to prune? Is this about R or about D3.js?

Comment: It's an r problem. I want to filter a dataframe based on tree characteristics

Comment: Alright. I removed the d3 tag because tags should indicate what the question is about, not what is around.

Comment: maybe it can be done on the js side. how can i traverse on the tree and prune siblings that dont have children?

Comment: the [js code](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083) for the d3 tree

Comment: Fair enough, but if there is no problem with your JS code and if you don't want to prune with D3, then this is not a D3 issue and should not be tagged as such.

Comment: i am asking. if i wanted to add to the js code a function that prunes the tree how would i do that

Comment: Ah, this changes things. This requires swapping tags: get rid of [tag:r], enter [tag:d3]. Please revise you question then: update the tags, add the parts of your code relevant to this problem to the question itself, add your data structure and clearly state what you are after. Be as specific as possible and I am pretty sure the usual suspects will soon be there to get this going.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to represent your tree in a more efficient way. your current representation (in which each row seem to represent a branch in the tree) makes it hard to work with. a better representation would be - a row for each node, with a node_id (see below). you build this table for the whole tree. you add a vector/column for "visibility", and then you don't need to recreate/filter the dataset each time you exapnd/collapse on a node (explained later). so for your given tree your basic representation will look like:

```
tree = data.frame(
        node_id = 1:10,
        node_data = c("ggplot",4,6,8,0,1,0,1,0,1),
        parent_id = c(NA,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,6,6),
        visible = rep(T,10)
      )
```

Now, to really work with a tree it is often useful to create an asjacency matrix. so if you have N nodes (10 in our case) then you get an N*N binary matrix in which A(i,j)=1 iff i is the parent of j. you can create your adjacency matrix from the above using the code below:

```
A = matrix(0,nrow = nrow(tree),ncol=nrow(tree))
A[cbind(tree$parent_id,tree$node_id)] = 1
```

Now, what you really need is a "decendency matrix", a matrix B in which B(i,j)=1 iff j is a decendent of i. you get that by multiplying A by itself (matrix multiplication) and adding those powers of A. if there are d levels to the tree A^(d+1)=0, so no need to go beyond that. so:

```
B = A + A%*%A + A%*%A%*%A  #that should be enough here, more generally you'd need some looping to add enough powers of A
B0 = 0+ (B>0)
```

Now. to prune the tree at node i you need the following:

```
prune_at = function(node_id,decenedency,current_visibility) {
    to_prune = which(decendency[node_id,]>0)
    new_visibility = current_visibility
    new_visibility[to_prune] = F
    new_visibility
}

# for example:
pruned = prune_at(2,B0,tree$visibility)
```

To expand a visible node, so that you'd see its children:

```
expand_at = function(node_id,adjacency,current_visibility) {
    new_visibility = current_visibility
    if(current_visibility[node_id]==T) {
        to_expand = which(adjacency[node_id,]==1)
        new_visibility[to_expand] = T
    }
    new_visibility
}

#example
expand_at(2,A,pruned)
```

So in all - you create those representation once for the whole dataset. then all you need is to play with the "visibility" vector that change from one operation to the other stating which nodes are visible.

I hope it makes sense.